# how could i filter NSString from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to filter `NSString` from `NSDictionary` to load image but I still don't know how to do it even though I try many ways to achieve .

```
    arr = [allJson allValues];


    NSMutableArray *imagearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0;i < arr.count; i++)
    {
        [imagearray addObject:arr[i][@"pic_url"]] ;

    }
```

but when set breakpoint on the arr had 10 object

imagearray is 0 object

Here is my allJson data

"

```
        allen = mock;
        category = "\U5c71\U5be8/\U5632\U8af7";
        clickRate = 618;
        director = "\U5091\U745e\U5fb7\U5b54\U6069";
        language = "\U82f1\U8a9e";
        movieTime = 83;
        "name_en" = "Atlantic Rim";
        "name_zh" = "\U74b0\U5927\U897f\U6d0b";
        nation = "\U7f8e\U570b";
        "picH_url" = "http://api.dvacloud.com/pics/picH/1.jpg";
        "pic_url" = "http://api.dvacloud.com/pics/1.jpg";
        ranking = "\U4fdd\U8b77\U7d1a";
```

Comment: is your dictionary is a collection of array...and what is the name of key for array and your `pic_url` is at which index

Comment: please provide NSLog of 'allJson'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below code, It will work if you are having right json dictionary,

```
NSMutableArray *imagearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0;i < arr.count; i++)
{
    [imagearray addObject:[[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"pic_url"]];
}
```

Hope this will work for u.